# How to fix date-fns adding 1 hour to passed time in Node.js reservation system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, date-fns

I'm using node js and am trying to make a reservation system.
I'm using prisma to work on my database and prisma's default datetime format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z.

I'm passing the datetime as 2023-06-06T12:00:00.000Z and it is being stored correctly on my database. However, I'm trying to send confirmation and cancelation emails to each user creating or removing a reservation and I don't want to send an email saying "Reservation for 2023-06-06T12:00:00.000Z confirmed".
For that reason, I tried using date-fns and created a variable:

```
import { format } from "date-fns"

const formattedReservationHour = format(
  new Date(reservation_hour),
  "HH:mm"
);
```

When I console log this formattedReservationHour or received the email, for some reason date-fns is adding 1 hour to the time I pass it (instead of 12:00, it turns into 13:00). How can I fix this?

Please let me know if you can help in some way.

Comment: You should specify the timezone to use.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do it but I worked around it using the Moment library.

This was the solution:

```
import moment from "moment";

const formattedReservationHour = moment.utc(reservation_hour).format("HH:mm");
```

It now provides the correct hour I pass on the JSON.
Before, if I passed 12:00, the `formattedReservationHour` would be 13:00. Now it stays 12:00.